# Chrome Dev Tools - Determine when a string is first referenced?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Pretty simple question I'm hoping.  Basically I have a string that I know is used somewhere in javascript that is about 10K lines, the problem is I can't find where the string was created (I've tried doing breakpoints and following the tree but it always starts on an anonymous function, so this isn't a help).

Any ideas as to how I can basically be like "hey chrome, tell me when this string first appears"?

Thanks!

Comment: To clarify: you want to know the first time a particular string *value* is assigned to *any variable*? That's very hard. Do you merely need to know when a *particular variable* is set to a particular value? That's much easier.

Comment: Just when the string is used, anywhere in the javascript.  I wasn't sure if there was basically a way to script "pausing" on each line and checking references, or something similar.

Comment: You can use watch expressions in the debugger, but you need to know what variable identifier to watch. To my knowledge, you can't say "watch every variable that currently exists and see if it holds this string".

Comment: So I do know what variables I want to watch, but when I add them to watch expressions nothing ever happens

Comment: @Geesu you need to pause script execution to see it auto-updating.